# Disable dhcp service in dnsmasq

Tags: dnsmasq

I would like to use only dnsmasq to forward all dns requests to google's dns server and disable dhcp...

How can I achieve this result?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

dnsmasq has dhcp server disabled by default.
To enable it you have to uncomment dhcp-related lines in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`

to forward all requests to 208.67.222.222 it's sufficient to add (without touching dnsmasq config) in `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1 
# In order to configure dnsmasq to act as cache for the host on which  it
# is  running, put [as the first line] "nameserver  127.0.0.1" in /etc/resolv.conf to force
# local processes to send queries to dnsmasq. [...]
# dnsmasq is smart enough to ignore this line and forward all queries appropriately, 
# while all other applications will send all their queries to dnsmasq. 
nameserver 208.67.222.222
```

That's it :)

Comment: @CraigHicks Please explain better. The question here is: "Disable dhcp service in dnsmasq"

Comment: My mistake - sorry.

Answer (score 7):

Just comment out the dhcp-related lines in your dnsmasq.conf file and then restart dnsmasq.

Answer (score 0):

To disable DHCP, comment out all of the "dhcp-range" settings in the dnsmaq.conf file, and remove all "--dhcp-range" command line options used when starting the "dnsmasq" executable program/daemon.

Example filename: /etc/dnsmasq.conf

Example commented out line:

```
#dhcp-range=192.168.0.50,192.168.0.150,12h
```

Source: [dnsmasq doc](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html)

Answer (score 0):

On **Ubuntu [18.04]**: comment out all

```
dhcp-*
dhcp-range=
```

lines in both files:

> /etc/dnsmasq.d/dhcp-settings

and

> /etc/dnsmasq.conf

Then just restart the service:
`sudo systemctl restart dnsmasq`